# Stop Apache2 from restarting on port 80 on boot

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, port

I'm constantly having to stop Apache2 from running on port 80. I have done everything I can think of:

1. sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
2. sudo update-rc.d -f  apache2 remove
3. sudo apt remove apache2.*

However, whenever I reboot my computer Apache2 somehow starts up on port 80 again and the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" shows up again at localhost.

I inevitably end up running lengthy builds that use port 80 and forget to stop the Apache2 service on port 80. I would just like to stop Apache2 forever and be done with it.

I can't find any in formation on how to stop Apache2 from restarting on boot.

Thanks, 
Tyler

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you state you "have done everything" you can think of - would you mind [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/578929/edit) your question to include a list of steps taken (and found ineffective)? Otherwise you will attract answers suggesting solutions you have already tried ...

Comment: Which Ubuntu Version are you using? Did the first two commands you mentioned return an error message? I'm asking because any recent versions of Ubuntu use `systemd`, hence you should use `systemctl disable apache2.service` . As to why removing doesn't help, I can't tell.

Comment: Did you consider asking Apache to listen to another port by configuring it to do so? Use the `Listen <portnumber>` configuration.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I did change the ports prior to uninstalling Apache2 but the port didn't change surprisingly. That's when I gave up and just uninstalled Apache2. It seems like two versions of Apache2 are running. I just don'e know how or where.

Comment: @AdminBee, I get Unit file apache2.service does not exist

Comment: is your question "Stop Apache2 from restarting on boot" ?

Comment: Maybe it's not actually apache2 that is running on port 80. Have a look at `sudo lsof -i -P -n`.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the comments by [AdminBee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578929/stop-apache2-from-restarting-on-port-80-on-boot#comment1077435_578929), you need to disable the service on an Ubuntu version with `systemd`:

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
```

Use `enable` to enable the service again.

You can then still start/stop the service manually with

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service apache2 stop
```

if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I ran 
`sudo systemctl disable apache2` 
but since I uninstalled apache2 already I get: 
**Failed to disable unit: Unit file apache2.service does not exist.**

Are there two installations of apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

To remove Apache:

`sudo apt purge apache*`

The dot you have after apache2 is most likely to be your problem.

You can check this has worked by using `dpkg`:

`dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep -i apache`

This will show all currently installed packages matching the (case insensitive) string apache

Comment: since I have already removed apache2 after running `sudo apt purge apache*` I get a list of all the the apache packages that are not installed i.e.
**Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed**
and
**0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded**

Comment: In your initial question, you suggested you had issued the command `sudo apt remove apache.*` (with a dot between the apache and the *). This would not have resulted in removal, as intended, hence my answer. I assume you have restarted the machine, since removal?